# Xcode : import folder/group

Tags: cocoa, xcode, sdk, import, directory

Is it possible to import a folder/group in stead of importing file per file in the .m ?
**Example file per file**:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ThirdViewController.h"
```

**So it is possible to make it like that (folder contains first-second and thirdviewcontroller)** :

```
#import "Folder"
```

Is it possible ?
Cause it's very annoying to import file per file when you have a lot of files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, but you can import your files in the precompiled header, so you import them just once, and they will be available globally...

**EDIT**

Imagine your project's name is MyApp.
You got a precompiled header filed named `MyApp-Prefix.pch`

```
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_3_0
    #warning "This project uses features only available in iPhone SDK 3.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    /* Your imports here */

#endif
```

This particular header file will be automatically imported in all your files, so you can add here the `#import` directives you need, so you don't have to write them on all your files.

Comment: Could you explaine with an example please ? I don't understand so good. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

You can't directly import everything in a folder, but you can make an extra header file that does all of the imports in one place.  Then you just import the new header file wherever you need it.

e.g. in a new `ViewControllers.h` file put just these lines:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ThirdViewController.h"
```

And then put `#import "ViewControllers.h"` wherever you need it.

Comment: Yes thanks , but the idea is to write the less possible.  With your option I still have to write them. So i actually gain noting.  But still thanks ;)